# How to count lines in a document?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, scripting

I have lines like these, and I want to know how many lines I actually have...

```
09:16:39 AM  all    2.00    0.00    4.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   94.00
09:16:40 AM  all    5.00    0.00    0.00    4.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   91.00
09:16:41 AM  all    0.00    0.00    4.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.00
09:16:42 AM  all    3.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.00
09:16:43 AM  all    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.00
09:16:44 AM  all    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
09:16:45 AM  all    2.00    0.00    6.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.00
```

Is there a way to count them all using linux commands?

Comment: Open file using vim, then type `g <Ctrl-g>`, It will show you number of lines, words, columns and bytes

Answer (score 2524, accepted):

Use `wc`:

```
wc -l <filename>
```

This will output the number of lines in `<filename>`:

```
$ wc -l /dir/file.txt
3272485 /dir/file.txt
```

Or, to omit the `<filename>` from the result use `wc -l < <filename>`:

```
$ wc -l < /dir/file.txt
3272485
```

You can also pipe data to `wc` as well:

```
$ cat /dir/file.txt | wc -l
3272485
$ curl yahoo.com --silent | wc -l
63
```

Comment: this is great!! you might use awk to get rid of the file name appended to the line number as such: `wc -l <file> | awk '{print $1}`

Comment: Even shorter, you could do `wc -l < <filename>`

Comment: This gives me one extra line then all the lines?

Comment: @GGB667 you can also get rid of the file name with `cat <file> | wc -l`

Comment: and with `watch wc -l <filename>` you can follow this file in real-time. That's useful for log files for example.

Comment: None of the suggestions in this answer are actually bash answers. But while we're recommending other tools, you could avoid the whitespace by just using awk: `awk 'END{print NR}' /dir/file.txt`, or sed: `sed -n '$=' /dir/file.txt`.  Or heck, if you wanted an actual **bash** solution, you could count the files in a loop!  `while read _; do ((n++)); done < /dir/file.txt; echo $n`.

Comment: So simple, thanks .... How could I write this into a variable inside a bash script so that I can collect line counts from various files and then use those variables later on in my script. So like $LINECOUNT1 (from file1.txt) $LINECOUNT2 (from file2.txt) etc ??? And then if I want to I can just take a sum of variable1 + variable2 +variable3 etc.

Comment: Never mind figured it out
WC1=$(wc -l < file1.txt)
WC2=$(wc -l < file2.txt)

Comment: Beware that wc -l counts "newlines". If you have a file with 2 lines of text and one "newline" symbol between them, wc will output "1" instead of "2".

Comment: @user85509 wc -l gives the number of new lines, which might be different from actual number of lines in a file. (Usually wc -l gives 1 less than actual no of lines)

Comment: In a bash script, how do I assign the output of `wc -l < /dir/file.txt` to a variable?

Comment: @jovan I would use `$()` (evaluation) operator.

Comment: @asdf Actually, `wc -l` usually gives the real number of lines in a compliant Linux text file. The last line in a file is always supposed to be `\n`, so that `cat <file>` prints the prompt on a new line, wc -l gives the right line count, etc. A lot of text editors (and IDEs) will always introduce a newline at the end of a text file when you save it for this reason. So you shouldn't assume you need to increment; if you care, you should check whether it's non-compliant (last char is not `'\n'`), and add one in that case.

Comment: **This answer is not POSIX-compliant and can easily miscount lines.** `wc` counts newlines, the character, and not lines. This will lead to miscounts if your EOF is not `\n`, which POSIX does not require. I've answered this in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59573533/2899048).

Answer (score 164):

To count all lines use:

```
$ wc -l file
```

To filter and count only lines with pattern use:

```
$ grep -w "pattern" -c file
```

Or use -v to invert match:

```
$ grep -w "pattern" -c -v file
```

See the grep man page to take a look at the -e,-i and -x args...

Comment: Oddly sometimes the `grep -c` works better for me. Mainly due to `wc -l` annoying "feature" padding space prefix.

Comment: Additionally when your last line does not end with an LF or CRLF `wc -l` gives out a wrong number of lines as it only counts line endings. So `grep` with a pattern like `^.*$` will actually give you the true line number.

Answer (score 84):

```
wc -l <file.txt>
```

Or

```
command | wc -l
```

Answer (score 76):

### `wc -l` does not count lines.

Yes, this answer may be a bit late to the party, but I haven't found anyone document a more robust solution in the answers yet.

Contrary to popular belief, POSIX does not require files to end with a newline character at all. Yes, the definition of a [POSIX 3.206 Line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) is as follows:

> A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a terminating  character.

However, what many people are not aware of is that POSIX also defines [POSIX 3.195 Incomplete Line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_195) as:

> A sequence of one or more non- <newline> characters at the end of the file.

Hence, files without a trailing `LF` are perfectly POSIX-compliant.

**If you choose not to support both EOF types, your program is not POSIX-compliant.**

As an example, let's have look at the following file.

```
1 This is the first line.
2 This is the second line.
```

No matter the EOF, I'm sure you would agree that there are two lines. You figured that out by looking at how many lines have been started, not by looking at how many lines have been terminated. In other words, as per POSIX, these two files both have the same amount of lines:

```
1 This is the first line.\n
2 This is the second line.\n
```

```
1 This is the first line.\n
2 This is the second line.
```

The man page is relatively clear about `wc` counting newlines, with a newline just being a `0x0a` character:

```
NAME
       wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file
```

Hence, `wc` doesn't even attempt to count what you might call a "line". Using `wc` to count lines can very well lead to miscounts, depending on the EOF of your input file.

### POSIX-compliant solution

You can use `grep` to count *lines* just as in the example above. This solution is both more robust and precise, and it supports all the different flavors of what a line in your file could be:

- [POSIX 3.75 Blank Line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_75)
- [POSIX 3.145 Empty Line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_145)
- [POSIX 3.195 Incomplete Line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_195)
- [POSIX 3.206 Line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206)

```
$ grep -c ^ FILE
```

Comment: This should be the accepted asnwer. Not only because it is correct but also because `grep` is more that twice faster than `wc`.

Comment: Wow, this is a good answer. It needs to be the accepted answer because of good explanation and POSIX specs are clearly outlined.

Comment: Very nice: you might want to comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692/8344060)

Comment: On spot with what was needed in the question

Comment: This is the best answer because this is true, more precise than the other answers, and **that darn set of spaces in the beginning of `wc` output doesn't show up with `grep`**. I'm using the number of lines in a file for mathematical processing in a program, and those spaces are a pain, especially because I can't use `cut` since I don't know how many digits are going to be in the number of lines, so I can't always just cut out the number. This just outputs a number and nothing but a number. It should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: Another reason why a file doesn't requires to finish with a newline, `grep -f ` will see the last line as a pattern and match anything.

Answer (score 56):

there are many ways. using `wc` is one.

`wc -l file`

others include

`awk 'END{print NR}' file`

`sed -n '$=' file` (GNU sed)

```
grep -c ".*" file
```

Comment: Yes, but `wc -l file` gives you the number of lines AND the filename to get just the filename you can do: `filename.wc -l < /filepath/filename.ext`

Comment: Using the GNU grep -H argument returns filename and count.  `grep -Hc ".*" file`

Comment: I voted this solutions because `wc -l` counts newline characters and not the actual lines in a file. All the other commands included in this answer will give you the right number in case you need the lines.

Answer (score 36):

The tool `wc` is the "word counter" in UNIX and UNIX-like operating systems, but you can also use it to count lines in a file by adding the `-l` option.

`wc -l foo` will count the number of lines in `foo`. You can also pipe output from a program like this: `ls -l | wc -l`, which will tell you how many files are in the current directory (plus one).

Comment: `ls -l | wc -l`  will actually give you the number of files in the directory +1 for the total size line.  you can do `ls -ld * | wc -l` to get the correct number of files.

Answer (score 29):

If you want to check the total line of all the files in a directory ,you can use find and wc:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} +
```

Answer (score 26):

Use `wc`:

```
wc -l <filename>
```

Answer (score 16):

If all you want is the number of lines (and not the number of lines and the stupid file name coming back):

```
wc -l < /filepath/filename.ext
```

As previously mentioned these also work (but are inferior for other reasons):

```
awk 'END{print NR}' file       # not on all unixes
sed -n '$=' file               # (GNU sed) also not on all unixes
grep -c ".*" file              # overkill and probably also slower
```

Comment: This answer was posted 3 years after the question was asked and it is just copying other ones. The first part is the trivial and the second is all [ghostdog's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3137621/1983854) was adding. Downvoting.

Comment: 4 years on.. downvoting. Let's see if we can get a decade long downvote streak!

Comment: No, you are wrong; ghostdog's answer does not answer the original question.  It gives you the number of lines AND the filename.  To get just the filename you can do: filename.wc -l < /filepath/filename.ext.  Which is why I posted the answer.  awk, sed and grep are all slightly inferior ways of doing this.  The proper way is the one I listed.

Answer (score 11):

Use `nl` like this:

```
nl filename
```

From `man nl`:

> Write  each  FILE to standard output, with line numbers added.  With
>   no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

Comment: This is the first answer I have found that works with a file that has a single line of text that does not end in a newline, which `wc -l` reports as 0. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I've been using this:

```
cat myfile.txt | wc -l
```

I prefer it over the accepted answer because it does not print the filename, and you don't have to use `awk` to fix that. Accepted answer:

`wc -l myfile.txt`

But I think the best one is GGB667's answer:

`wc -l < myfile.txt`

I will probably be using that from now on. It's slightly shorter than my way. I am putting up my old way of doing it in case anyone prefers it. The output is the same with those two methods.

Comment: the first and last method are the same. the last one is better because it doesn't spawn an extra process

Answer (score 7):

Above are the preferred  method but "cat" command can also helpful:

```
cat -n <filename>
```

Will show you whole content of file with line numbers.

Answer (score 6):

**wc -l file_name**

for eg: wc -l file.txt

it will give you the total number of lines in that file

for getting last line use **tail -1 file_name**

Answer (score 5):

I saw this question while I was looking for a way to count multiple files lines, 
so if you want to count multiple file lines of a .txt file you can do this,

```
cat *.txt | wc -l
```

it will also run on one .txt file ;)

Answer (score 5):

`wc -l <filename>`

This will give you number of lines and filename in output.

Eg.

`wc -l  24-11-2019-04-33-01-url_creator.log`

Output

`63 24-11-2019-04-33-01-url_creator.log`

Use

`wc -l <filename>|cut -d\  -f 1`

to get only number of lines in output.

Eg.

`wc -l  24-11-2019-04-33-01-url_creator.log|cut -d\  -f 1`

Output

`63`

Comment: Where is the benefit of repeating the accepted (ten years old) answer?

Comment: Because I couldn't find command to get only line numbers in output in this thread.

Comment: It's the second example in the accepted answer. `wc -l < filename`

Comment: wc -l < filename > gives filename as well as number of lines in output.

Comment: No, `wc -l < filename` is different to `wc -l filename`, the first uses redirection and then there isn't any filename in the output, like shown in [the answer from user85509](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3137099/463115)

Answer (score 4):

```
cat file.log | wc -l | grep -oE '\d+'
```

- `grep -oE '\d+'`: In order to return the digit numbers **ONLY**.

Answer (score 4):

count number of lines and store result in variable use this command:

`count=$(wc -l < file.txt)
echo "Number of lines: $count"`

Answer (score 4):

I tried wc -l to get the number of line from the file name

To do more filtering for example want to count to the number of commented lines from the file use grep '#' Filename.txt | wc -l

```
echo  "No of files in the file $FILENAME"
wc -l < $FILENAME
echo total number of commented lines
echo $FILENAME
grep '#' $FILENAME | wc -l
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in case. It's all possible to do it with many files in conjunction with the **find** command.

```
find . -name '*.java' | xargs wc -l
```

Comment: Don't use `xargs`. The `find` command has an `-exec` verb that is much simpler to use. Someone already suggested its use 6 years ago, although this question does not ask anything about multiple files. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016686

Answer (score 3):

```
wc -l file.txt | cut -f3 -d" "
```

Returns only the number of lines

Answer (score 3):

Redirection/Piping the output of the file to `wc -l` should suffice, like the following:

```
cat /etc/fstab | wc -l
```

which then would provide the no. of lines only.

Answer (score 3):

Or count all lines in subdirectories with a file name pattern (e.g. logfiles with timestamps in the file name):

```
wc -l ./**/*_SuccessLog.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

This drop-in portable shell function [<sup>[ℹ]</sup>](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05)  works like a charm. Just add the following snippet to your **`.bashrc`** file *(or the equivalent for your shell environment)*.

```sh
# ---------------------------------------------
#  Count lines in a file
#
#  @1 = path to file
#
#  EXAMPLE USAGE: `count_file_lines $HISTFILE`
# ---------------------------------------------
count_file_lines() {
    local subj=$(wc -l $1)
    subj="${subj//$1/}"
    echo ${subj//[[:space:]]}
}
```

---

This should be fully compatible with all [POSIX-compliant shells](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-is-posix-shell/) in addition to [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) and [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell).

Answer (score 3):

Awk saves <s>lives</s>time (and lines too):

```
awk '{c++};END{print c}' < file
```

If you want to make sure you are not counting empty lines, you can do:

```
awk '{/^./ && c++};END{print c}' < file
```

Comment: `awk` used this way is 16 times slower than `grep -c '^'`

Comment: @Eric does `grep` also count the lines?

Comment: sure: `grep -c -E ^` will count the number of "start of line" markers, hence the number of lines.

Comment: @Eric Ah cool, cool. I was going to suggest you post that answer, but it looks like [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3137127/2089675) else already did so. Anyways, when I posted this answer, I just discovered `awk`, and this was one of the many things I discovered it could do. I also just tested with a 1GB file, and awk was only 4x slower, not 16x. I created the test file using `base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 1000000000`, but with smaller files (which is most likely what these answers will be used for), the speed is hardly variable

Comment: Yeah I get also a ratio of 4 with this sort of files. So depending on the file, yout mileage may vary. The point is that it's always in benefit of `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is *old* but still: ***Count filtered lines***

My file looks like:

```
Number of files sent
Company 1 file: foo.pdf OK
Company 1 file: foo.csv OK
Company 1 file: foo.msg OK
Company 2 file: foo.pdf OK
Company 2 file: foo.csv OK
Company 2 file: foo.msg Error
Company 3 file: foo.pdf OK
Company 3 file: foo.csv OK
Company 3 file: foo.msg Error
Company 4 file: foo.pdf OK
Company 4 file: foo.csv OK
Company 4 file: foo.msg Error
```

If I want to know how many files are sent OK:

```
grep "OK" <filename> | wc -l
```

OR

```
grep -c "OK" filename
```

Answer (score 1):

As others said `wc -l` is the best solution, but for future reference you can use Perl:

```
perl -lne 'END { print $. }'
```

`$.` contains line number and `END` block will execute at the end of script.

Comment: Does not work:
`dir | perl -lne 'END { print $. }'
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.'`

Comment: @VeikkoW Works for me. If you are on Windows, different quoting rules apply; but the OP asked about Linux / Bash.

Comment: `perl -lne '}{ print $. '` does the same.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a program to do this ( with `node` )

```
npm install gimme-lines
gimme-lines verbose --exclude=node_modules,public,vendor --exclude_extensions=html
```

https://github.com/danschumann/gimme-lines/tree/master

Comment: Isn't that like using an F16 to kill garden weeds?

Answer (score 1):

if you're on some sort of BSD-based system like macOS, i'd recommend the gnu version of wc. It doesn't trip up on certain binary files the way BSD wc does. At least it's still somewhat usable performance. On the other hand, BSD tail is slow as ............zzzzzzzzzz...........

As for AWK, only a minor caveat though - since it operates under the default assumption of lines, meaning `\n`, if your file just happens not to have a trailing new line delimiter, AWK will over count it by 1 compared to either BSD or GNU wc. Also, if you're piping in things with no new lines at all, such as `echo -n`, depending on whether you're measuring at the `END { }` section or `FNR==1`, the NR will be different.