# Count lines of CLI output in linux

Tags: linux, count, command-line-interface

Hi have the following command:

```
lsscsi | grep HITACHI | awk '{print $6}'
```

I want that the output will be the number of lines of the original output.
For example, if the original output is:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
```

The final output will be `3`.

Comment: `lsscsi | grep HITACHI | awk '{print $6}' | wc -l`

Comment: Thanks. So easy :)

Comment: @JuanTomas Never use `grep foo | awk '{print $1}'`. It should be `awk '/foo/{print $1}'`. If you use `awk`, `grep` is not required meaning unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count lines in a document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137094/how-to-count-lines-in-a-document)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically the command `wc -l` can be used to count the lines in a file or pipe. However, since you want to count the number of lines after a filter has been applied I would recommend to use `grep` for that:

```
lsscsi | grep -c 'HITACHI'
```

`-c` just prints the number of matching lines.

---

Another thing. In your example you are using `grep .. | awk`. That's a useless use of `grep`. It should be

```
lsscsi | awk '/HITACHI/{print $6}'
```

Comment: What is meant here is that `lsscsi | grep -c 'HITACHI'` and `lsscsi | grep 'HITACHI'|wc -l` will have the same console output: just the number of lines.