# What does the `<` operator do in shell?

Tags: shell

I was reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137094/how-to-count-lines-in-a-document), in which someone is trying to get the number of lines in a file from the shell. From the comments, I saw and implemented that the following:

```
$ wc -l myfile.txt
30213 myfile.txt

$ wc -l < <filename>
30213
```

What I don't understand is, what the `<` operator is doing here. Can someone explain why the `<` operator chops off the file name from the output in this case?

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the `filename` is supplied as an argument when calling `wc`, this causes `wc` to include it in the output.

In the second case, stdin is redirected from `filename`, this makes `wc` "unaware" of the file and thus not able to print its name. This is equivalent to calling `cat filename | wc -l`.

So to answer your question, operator `<` redirects input file descriptor to read from a given file. If descriptor number is not explicitly specified, then it defaults to standard input (fd 0). See [here for a formal reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_01) and [here for a convenient description](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators).

Comment: `<` operator redirects any file descriptors input, STDIN is just default if you don't assign a file descriptor.

Comment: @123 I'm well aware of that, I was referring to OP's question.

Comment: It's just that you put `operator < redirects the standard input.` which seems like a general statement.

Comment: That's a fair remark, I've modified the answer to be more precise.

Answer (score 2):

`wc` outputs the file name as part of the output when it reads from a file.

The `<` redirects input and output between files/programs, following the direction of the "arrow". For more information on I/O redirection, [this](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0070.php) is a pretty handy link. The reason that the file name is "chopped off" is because `wc` is technically no longer reading from a file.

Comment: `wc` is reading from a file, it just doesn't know the name of the file it is reading from.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I was under the impression that redirecting the input and output means that wc is just reading from its own stdin (now modified to the file) rather than accessing the file directly, is that not correct?

Comment: wc is reading from its stdin.  Which is a file that it access directly.

Comment: @WilliamPursell What are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about the fact that if you invoke `wc < file`, then the stdin of the process is the file.  And `wc` accesses that file directly.  What is confusing about that statement?  Write a program that invokes `fseek` on stdin.  Use `<` to connect a file to the stdin on an invocation of that program.  fseek will (probably) succeed.  Why?  Because stdin is the file, and the program is accessing it directly.

Comment: @123 ^^ See previous comment.