# Open csv file with Pandas and delete if has only 1 row

Tags: python, pandas, opencsv

I have a task to create a script to ssh to list of 10 cisco routers weekly and check for config changes and send notification. So i have in place the script that logs and run the command and send it to csv. I have modified so if there is not changes all I have in the csv will be for example:
rtr0003# -which is  the router name only. If there will be conf change the excel will have inside for example:

[image]

My question is how to run pandas to open each file  and if it sees only one line/row to delete the excel file and if more lines to skip it.

This is how i write the files:

```
files = glob.glob('*.csv')
for file in files:
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    df=df.dropna()
    df.to_csv(file,index=False)
    df1=pd.read_csv(file,skiprows = 2)
    #df1=df1.drop(df1.tail(1))
    df1.to_csv(file,index=False)
```

Comment: Why use python / pandas for this at all? You could just do it in bash [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137094/how-to-count-lines-in-a-document)

Comment: @forgetso, But OP wants this in python as a choice :-)

Comment: all at once-using paramiko to ssh and run the command , then pandas to create and filter the csv and then send an email.Seems all easier then mixing bash , python etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os    
import glob
import csv

files = glob.glob('*.csv')

for file in files:
    with open(file,"r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
        data = list(reader)
        row_count = len(data)

    if row_count == 1:
        os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

csv_files = glob.glob('*.csv')
for file in csv_files:
    df_file = pd.read_csv(file, low_memory = False)
    if len(df_file) == 1:
        os.remove(file)
```

If you are using excel files, change

```
glob.glob('*.csv')
```

to

```
glob.glob('*.xlsx')
```

and

```
pd.read_csv(file, low_memory = False)
```

to

```
pd.read_excel(file)
```